# Preserving Android App Data

Tags: android, debugging

I need to debug a new version of my app using Android Studio without losing the SQLite database on the device. When I start the debugger and deploy the new app, will the data be preserved?

Comment: Data is only removed when you completely uninstall and reinstall the app.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set your keystore that you've been using so far as debug keystore, if you won't then you'll need to reinstall the app as the key signatures will be different. As Mark has said already, "Data is only removed when you uninstall and reinstall the app.".

Comment: I don't have a keystore, as far as I know.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html
Every app has a keystore. Please study the link before proceeding any further.